# Extend MTF LogFile to a file in desktop

Tags: logfile, computer-forensics

I am new to this simple thing,For my Windows Forensic Course, I extended $mft and $logFile to my folder in Desktop. I can see in the file properties that they are loaded. But when I visit the file, I can't see anything. I opened hidden files options, but it didn't work, what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

I found my answer:

Click on Start
Select Control Panel
Select Folder Options
Select the View tab
Scroll down the Advanced setting
Uncheck Hide protected operating system files
Click OK